# Download CodeIgniter older version 2.x

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I am new in CodeIngniter. And I dont want to download the latest version from http://ellislab.com/codeigniter

I want to work with older version of codeIgniter and I think that are not available on http://ellislab.com/codeigniter

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/installation/downloads.html 
If we click on any link on above page, it always redirect to http://ellislab.com/codeigniter

Can anybody tell me , from where can download older version.

Thanks

Comment: A quick [Google search](http://www.google.com/search?q=codeigniter+older+versions) goes [a long way](http://codeigniterplus.blogspot.com/2012/11/codeigniter-all-version-downloads.html).

Comment: what version that you need ?? you said `I am new in CodeIngniter`, i recommend just start with newer version : 2.1.4

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to fork it via [github](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/). if you couldn't find it, it is located on the release tab.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the download list of all versions <= 2.2.0

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/installation/downloads.html

Answer (score 0):

Links to old versions of CodeIgniter are listed on two web pages.

[PAGE 1: For CodeIgniter 2.x, use this link](https://codeigniter.com/userguide2/installation/downloads.html).  Please be advised that page contains a note that can be confusing.  On that page, Version 2.2.6 is marked "Current version." Version 2.2.6 is the last version of the 2.x series and it has reached the end of life. If you are looking for the most recent stable release of CodeIgniter, which is also marked Current Version, look on the download page for CodeIgniter 3.x

[PAGE 2: For CodeIgniter 3.x, use this link](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/installation/downloads.html).